# Setting up Activator in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

Im working on Play - Scala project and in order to use the framework correctly, I have to download some activator thing from this page : https://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted

The problem is that I cant find any activator to download, only Play templates or models.

Can you please help !

Comment: Activator is deprecated in Play 2.6

Comment: Your link redirects to https://developer.lightbend.com/start/ - is this what you meant to link to? What tutorial are you following?

Comment: @Lasf Okay thanks do you have any recent tutorial to advice ! I can't seem to find any new Play-Scala fresh tutorials !

Comment: Here you go: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Tutorials

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Yes It's that link that is given on the official doc https://www.playframework.com/documentation/fr/2.4.x/NewApplication this is what I'm folowing

Comment: @Lasf Thanks !!